# teamcity Failed to collect changes, error: Error getting latest revision: Error: Reading from the stream has failed

Tags: teamcity-9.0, plasticscm

I have upgraded teamcity from 8 to 9.1.1 version. I have created the build configuration with plastic-scm vcs type. On run build following error is displayed.

Failed to collect changes, error: Error getting latest revision: Error: Reading from the stream has failed.

Test connection is successful to plastic scm.
Can someone give advise on it.

Comment: I'm not familiar with plastic-scm, but could it be permissions? Have the credentials that TeamCity was running under changed?

Comment: Please, could you check if you are using the last available plugin at www.plasticscm.com ? I´ve just tested a new build using the last plugin version and TC 9.1.1 and I can´t reproduce any issue.
If you still face any issue, you can reach us at support at codicesoftware dot com and we will help you to debug and fix the problem.